# The report server cannot process the report. rsInvalidDataSourceReference

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008

I've deployed a report which I'm accessing from my application. The first time I try to access I get the message

> The report server cannot process the report. The data source connection information has been   deleted. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

However trying it the second time works just fine and the report shows properly. I deleted the datasource in ReportManager and created new one, but the error persists. Also deleted the report and added it again but to no avail.

Would appreciate any inputs on this issue. Thanks.

EDIT: Following code is called on button click. However this code throws no error or exceptions. When the report pop-up opens it just displays the error message I've listed above. On closing the pop-up and clicking the button again the report displays proper data.

```
        SchedulePopup.Open = true;
        SchedulePopup.Title = "Schedule Report";
        ReportViewer4.Visible = true;
        ReportViewer4.ServerReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverPath"] + "Schedule";

        List<ReportParameter> paralist = new List<ReportParameter>();
        ReportParameter reportParam = new ReportParameter("OrganisationId", txtOrganisationId.Text);
        ReportParameter reportParam1 = new ReportParameter("LocationId", txtLocationId.Text);
        ReportParameter reportParam2 = new ReportParameter("PrdAcctId", txtProductAccountId.Text);
        ReportParameter reportParam3 = new ReportParameter("CustomerId", txtCustomerId.Text);

        paralist.Add(reportParam);
        paralist.Add(reportParam1);
        paralist.Add(reportParam2);
        paralist.Add(reportParam3);
        ReportViewer4.ServerReport.SetParameters(paralist);
        ReportViewer4.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: First post your code, to clarify your doubts.

Comment: posted the code snippet. Can't understand whats the problem first time around since it works 2nd time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set a valid report path on the control on Init or Load

```
ReportViewer4.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/REPORTPATH";
```

Comment: Changed path-setting from button click to Init and worked like a charm. Can't understand what was wrong with earlier implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

navigating to the report deployment server (via browser) and opening the report from the list solves this sort of issues.